# Lumen How to validate image upload and display an alert on the frontend?

Tags: laravel, angular, lumen

I am building a web app using angular2 for my frontend and lumen for my backend. I have a form where a user can upload a picture but I want to add validation so the user can only upload valid image formats (JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc) and the file cannot be larger than 32mb. I want to return a response to my frontend as an alert if any of these conditions are not met

The upload form (angular2)

```
<form ngNoForm action=""
      target="_blank"
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

How I'm saving it to the database

```
public function imageUpload(Request $request) {

    // Check to make sure file is valid and doesnt exceed 32mb or display alert

    $file = $request->file('image');
    $imagedata = file_get_contents($file);
    $base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);

    if (DB::table('paint')->where('id', 1)
                          ->update(['pic' => $base64]))
    {
         //Display alert on frontend after pic sucessfully uploaded
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function imageUpload(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|max:32.896'
    ]);
    //rest of your code
}
```

You can call the validate method at the top of your functions. If one condition will fail it will return an error you can display. its checking:

- if the request contains the variable image
- if it's an image type (jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg)
- it's size is smaller or equal to 32.896 kb

for more rules you can check out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

in your html file you can do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let elements of errors">
  <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngFor="let element of elements">{{ element }}</div>
</div>
```

it depends how you want to display your messages.

Comment: Thanks. How do I get those errors to display as bootstrap alert `<div class="alert alert-warning"></div>` on my frontend? Currently it just displays the errors as a json array

Comment: you can iterate over it with 2 `ngFor` loops in your angular html file, updated my answer

Comment: How do I do that? What do I iterate over?

Comment: you iterate over the json response you got from the http request you made with angular to lumen.

Comment: im using action in my form to make the post request like in my original post

Comment: So you don't use angular for this, that's not good. The best way is to google for "upload image with angular2", otherwise you won't be able to show the errors